# Get data ajax from file local to server in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I want to get data ajax from file local to server.
I'm writting in Js as follow:

```
var UrlDetails = 'http://192.xxx.x.xxx:7000';
function createCORSRequest(method, url, asynch) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
        // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('MEDIBOX', 'login');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
        // XDomainRequest for IE.
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url, asynch);
    } else {
        // CORS not supported.
        xhr = null;
    }
    return xhr;
}

function getDoLogin(e, callback) {
    var url = UrlDetails + '/api/loginGET?username=' + e.id + '&password=' + e.password + '&f=json';
    var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url, true);
    if (xhr) {
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            try {
                if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                    } else {
                        xhr.status === 403 ? modalShow() : errorServer(xhr.status);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert('Caught Exception: ' + e.description);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
}
```

I call function                                                                `getDoLogin(e, f);`                                                                                                                 And I get a error from Chrome:                                                                                 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.xxx.x.xxx:7000/api/loginGET?username=1&password=1&f=json. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

It's only running with Jquery:

```
function getDoLoginJQuery(e) {
    return $.Deferred(function (d) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: UrlDetails +'/loginGET?username=' + e.id + '&password=' + e.password + '&f=json',
            cache: 'false',
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (a, b) {
            d.resolve(a)
        }).fail(function (a, b, c) {
            d.reject(a, b, c);
        })
    })
}
```

I don't know how to write in JS to run exactly.
(I'm sorry. My English is not good.)

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: `I don't know how to write in JS` - welcome to stack overflow, a place to ask for help with programming - notice it's not a place to get programming tutorials. If you don't know how to write javascript, step 1 is to learn how to write javascript. There are many sites where you can do this

Comment: I have edited my question. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `setRequestHeader`, like this:

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url, asynch) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
        // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
        // xhr.setRequestHeader('MEDIBOX', 'login');
        // xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
        // XDomainRequest for IE.
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url, asynch);
    } else {
        // CORS not supported.
        xhr = null;
    }
    return xhr;
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's running. If I want to run by POST, How does it run ?

Comment: Simply change `createCORSRequest('GET', url, true);` to `createCORSRequest('POST', url, true);` in the `getDoLogin()` function.

Comment: If I write "xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');" then my program don't run in file local but If I remove it then on my server, I receive some bytes => How do you read that bytes to json? Can you help me?

Comment: @KhuyênThuNguyễn I can barely answer you without known the details of response. Maybe you could ask a new question with providing more information.

Comment: I have created new question. Can you help me, please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885192/post-data-ajax-from-file-local-to-server-in-pure-javascript

Comment: @ Mo Shen, Can you answer why not it run when I use setRequestHeader in ajax, please ?