# Post data ajax from file local to server in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, post

I want to post info of login from file local to server. 
This is my code:

```
var UrlDetails = 'http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:xxxx';

function createCORSRequest(method, url, asynch) {
// Create the XHR object.
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
        // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
        //if (method == 'POST') {
            //    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        //}
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
        // XDomainRequest for IE.
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url, asynch);
    } else {
        // CORS not supported.
        xhr = null;
    }
    return xhr;
}

function postDoLogin(e, callback) {
    var url = UrlDetails + '/api/login?f=json';
    var xhr = createCORSRequest('POST', url, true);
    if (xhr) {
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
             try {
                 if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                     if (xhr.status === 200) {
                         callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                     } else {
                         xhr.status === 403 ? modalShow() : errorServer(xhr.status);
                     }
                 }
             }
             catch (e) {
                 alert('Caught Exception: ' + e.description);
             }
        };
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(e));
    }
}
```

In my server(I'm using Service API), I get data with:

```
 `RequestMessage = "<Binary>eyJpZCI6IjEiLCJwYXNzd29yZCI6IjEifQ==</Binary>";`
```

How do I parse RequestMessage to json to read?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the API you are using is returning base64 encoded string. If the API does not provide a feature to return JSON instead of base64 encoded string, then you can simply decode it in JavaScript using [atob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob).

So in your code instead of

```
callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
```

Use

```
var decoded = atob(xhr.responseText);
var json = JSON.parse(decoded);
callback(json);
```

Comment: I have a RequestMessage in server. Can you help me to read it?

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't know type of data that is base64 encoded string. I finded my answer from another question.                                                   public static JObject BinaryToString(string encodedString)
        {
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedString);
            return JObject.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
        }

Comment: Oh, I must have understood the question wrong. I thought that the response from server was encoded. You should've tagged Java since this is an issue occurring in a Java web server